# Semantical Error: Class Entity has no field or association named

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I want to add new field in my database and also use it in my entity in Doctrine. I've used another fields ,However I can't use the new one in my select query. Here is my Table's fields :

```
Food (food_id, food_status, food_name)
```

and I add new field `(food_sort -integer 10 unsigned)`

And here is my entity: (I've added new field in my entity)

```
class Food extends BaseEntity
{

 .
 .
 .
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="food_sort" , type="integer",  nullable=false)
     */
    protected $foodSort;

    /**
     * Get foodSort
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getFoodSort():int
    {
        return $this->foodSort;
    }

    /**
     * Set foodSort
     *
     * @param integer $foodSort
     *
     * @return Foods
     */
    public function setFoodSort(int $foodSort)
    {
        $this->foodSort = $foodSort;

        return $this;
    }
.
.
.    

}
```

Actually I get semantic error when I want to select food table.

**[Semantical Error]Error: Class App\Core\Model\Entities\Food has no field or association named foodSort**

whenever I remove this field from my select, it would be ok.

Any suggestion to fix it?

Comment: Hello, did you update your schema? `php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved in laravel

```
php artisan doctrine:clear:metadata:cache
```